# What is the purpose of EXCLUDE_FROM_SHLIBS

Tags: yocto, openembedded

In many bb, I see:

```
EXCLUDE_FROM_SHLIBS = "1"
```

From:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-EXCLUDE_FROM_SHLIBS

Triggers the OpenEmbedded build system's shared libraries resolver to exclude an entire package when scanning for shared libraries.

so,

Q1: What will libraries resolver do/scan for shared libraries?

Q2: What will it do after it found a shared lib?

Q3: What will happen if two or more packages generated the same shared lib( foo.so )?

Comment: Two packages installing the same file can't be installed on the same image. Does this help for the other questions? https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#automatically-added-runtime-dependencies

Comment: when assigning EXCLUDE_FROM_SHLIBS = "1", it means two packages CAN install to the same image?